# Wordpress giving me the index

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, page-template, single

i'm having a problem and i can't seem to figure out how to solve it. I'm just beginning to develop custom themes in wordpress and i wanted to create the custom template for portfolio and a single page for every single work in the portfolio.

the single-portfolio.php works fine but the page-portfolio.php loads the index instead. i tried setting the template in the builder but it doesn't work.

For the single-portfolio i am using a custom cpt i built where i can add new works just as i wold add a blog post and that seems to work just fine.. it just doesn't want to load the page-portfolio.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.. when creating the custom post type i set the argument "has_archive" to true and that was causing a conflict so my page-portfolio.php was not loaded. Also had to change the slug of the custom type field because it had the same slug as the page, so both of them were "portfolio".